# ClassNotFoundException when I try to deploy to Tomcat / tc Server in Eclipse / STS

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, maven, m2eclipse, eclipse-wtp

I'm new to Eclipse/STS, and I am having deploying to Tomcat / tcServer. My project builds just fine and deploys to Tomcat fine both in Netbeans and directly to Tomcat, but it will not deploy to Tomcat or tc Server in Eclipse.  I get a ClassNotFoundException for org.hibernate.HibernateException, which I know is on the included in the pom.

Here's my [log output](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/18643672/DO-NOT-ERASE/class-not-found-tomcat.log) if it helps.

Also in the markers view, I see the following build path problem:

```
Archive for required library: '~/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.1.1.Final/hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.pom' in project 'flamespass-web-dev' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a work around:
I noticed that I had hibernate-core:4.1.1.Final in my Dependency Hierarchy twice, so I tried a few things, and specifying the newest version of hibernate-core in my dependencyManagement node fixed my problem.

I am not sure why.  I can only assume that the two copies of hibernate-core:4.1.1 were creating some sort of ambiguity that m2eclipse or WTP couldn't understand even though my external Maven/Tomcat could.  I would really appreciate any explanation or better fixes anyone may have.  Thanks.

```xml
    ...
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: 4.1.2.Final solves the problem too and is less likely to break when moving from 4.1.1.Final