# Maven dependency Hibernate library cannot be read

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, maven, dependencies, m2eclipse

I'm  getting the following error in eclipse.

```
Archive for required library: '~/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.2.1.Final/hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar' in project
```

I've done `Maven`->`Update Project` and still it can't recognize the library.

I've verified that the jar file exists in the location mentioned.
This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144748/classnotfoundexception-when-i-try-to-deploy-to-tomcat-tc-server-in-eclipse-s) has the same error as I do but I double checked my pom and there are no duplicates.

Comment: try to delete dependency manually and reimport. If doesn't help try to use another version

Comment: Are you getting the error when deploying the application ? If yes , can you attach the logs .

Comment: Check the whole build on command line! Take a look at some kind of warnings or errors etc.?

Comment: @shevchik - thanks that somewhat helped. Changed version to 4.1.2 But what if I wanted to use the latest version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check access settings for file **'~/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.2.1.Final/hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar'** if you are using *nix system,
Also make sure you can open hibernate-core-4.2.1.Final.jar archive using third party tools e.g. 7zip or winrar. from my experience many times maven in eclipse does not properly download dependency and downloaded jar is corrupted. If that is the case you can manually download this jar and replace it in .m2 repository.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run maven task eclipse:eclipse from command prompt

open command prompt, Change Directory to project root directory and type
`mvn eclipse:eclipse`

And go back to eclipse and refresh project and see will it works :)